# gerrit and OpenID_SSO

Tags: java, openid, single-sign-on, gerrit

I set up a gerrit server.
For authentication gerrit allows among others [OpenId and OpenId_SSO](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5.2/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_auth_a_section_auth).
The first one works fine, but requires me to enter the whole long OpenId.
As I only want to allow a single provider the second option sounds perfect.

To use this, I have to supply the parameter `auth.openIdSsoUrl` which is "The SSO entry point URL".

How can I find out the correct URL to enter?

I already tried to use wireshark to monitor the http conversation during the normal OpenId login. But the URL involved there seems not to be the right one.

What exactly is an "entry point" in that context?

BTW: I currently use my own Atlassian Crowd as a OpenId server.

Edit: The java code involved can be found [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/master/gerrit-gwtui/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/client/auth/openid/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "entry point" is an OpenID endpoint URL. Using it to authenticate allows the OpenID server to say which user is authenticated, rather than requiring users to supply their own identifier. It's not used in the OpenID process unless you provide it, so it won't show in Wireshark logs.

From [Crowd 2.6](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Crowd+2.6+Release+Notes) there is an [endpoint URL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59277403#id-1.3WhatisanOpenIDURLoridentifier?-EndpointURLs), which will end in `openidserver/op`.